# How to avoid truncated stack traces with Java Flight Recorder

Tags: java, jvm, jmc, jfr, flamegraph

I am using Oracle [Java Flight Recorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/about.htm) to collect stack trace samples of a Java application. Theses stack traces allows me to eventually produce a [CPU Flamegraph](https://github.com/chrishantha/jfr-flame-graph).

My issue is that stack traces deeper than 64 frames are truncated by Java Flight Recorder. It's very easy to observe in the Flamegraph and using a debugger I can observe that no `FLRStackTrace` has more than 64 `FLRFrame`s and that almost all stack traces with 64 frames have their TruncationState set to `TRUNCATED`.

Does anyone know if this 64 frames limit can be increased ? Flamegraphs are useless if the stack traces are incomplete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep! But not if you're running on JRockit. If running on HotSpot, simply use the flag `-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=<n>`, where n, as you have discovered, defaults to 64.

More info here:
http://hirt.se/blog/?p=364

Comment: Thanks Marcus ! Any chance to be able to configure that at run time in the future ? I am a huge fan of the MBean feature and it would be great to be able to pass this as an option to jfrStart or through the settings.

Comment: I would think that the flag is a general setting for the flight recorder engine, which is already started when you call the MBean to start a particular recording, so you would still need the flag on the command line.

Comment: For JDK 9 we're looking at being able to configure the max stack depth at runtime, either as part of either the recording configuration or the template.